# Orgranizing a large amount of unique (non-product) static content in Magento?

Tags: seo, cms, magento

Some of you may have seen [my previous question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/18291/how-do-you-do-seo-past-on-page-optimization) where I was asking how websites that don't offer especially 'interesting' content go about link building - particularly in the case of e-commerce. The general outcome was that should webmasters want their 'boring' (but useful) websites to go out of their way and create interesting 'linkbait/worthy' content.

Now, the question:

In light of the response to my question, I'm going about making my company's online store more interesting. Part of this operation involves creating a fairly large base of relevant content to the products on offer (probably hundreds if not thousands of pages by the time (lots of time..) we're done). **Should I use Magento's built-in CMS to handle my pages or should I look at integrating another cms?** - I'm not interested in implementing a 'blogging' platform as that will come later on.

Edit: Should have mentioned, I'm using the community edition at the moment.

Comment: The Enterprise Edition of the CMS is different than the community edition CMS. Which version are you using?

Comment: Community edition at the moment with prospects of enterprise in early 2012 - will update the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the CMS functionality built into Magento meets your content management needs then use it. Having to install and maintain another piece of software just means more work for you. This especially holds true if security issues are found within the other CMS. You have two pieces of software that you must follow security updates for instead of one.

Comment: Yeah, I would ideally like to use the built-in CMS on offer, but was wondering if other webmasters had found it suitable for especially large amounts of content. The only problem I can see thus-far is organization within the admin interface. It's a shame pages can't be treated like products and be sorted into categories for the sake of organization on both the front and back end.

Answer (score 0):

**It depends on your future plans**

If you're going to upgrade to the Enterprise edition, then consider using the built-in CMS. One of the reasons to upgrade to enterprise is the enhanced CMS functionality (I haven't used it enough to give a thorough recommendation however) . If you use a different CMS software, it'll be an additional headache to move to the Magento Enterprise CMS.

If you're not going to upgrade I'd look at other CMS software, because there's a lot out there that's better than the built-in community edition CMS. [Magento connect](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect) offers a lot of additional plugins for community edition however, and you might find something in there that suits your needs and allows you to keep everything in magento.

You should plan out your content strategy first then make a decision on what you really need.

**Edit:** Also something to keep in mind, there's no guarantee of an improved CMS in magento community anytime soon, since the core developers of the product are focused on differentiating the enterprise edition from the community. In true CMS software, that's not the case, since you'll see improvements in the CMS software with every release since that's the core reason for the CMS software's existence.